# Can we use exponential function in a reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

If I have an NP-complete graph problem $P1$ whose instance, say, a graph $G$ and a positive integer $k$ and I have another graph problem $P2$ whose instance is a graph $G'$ and a positive integer $k'$. I would like to prove that $P2$ is NP-complete. The reduction is as follows:

- set $G'= G$ and
- set $k'= f(k)$.
- $P1$ is solved iff $P2$ is solved.

My question is: is this reduction correct when $f(k)$ is exponential function?, For simplicity, say, $f(k)=2^k$. I am afraid that this is no longer polynomial-time but then again calculating $2^k$ or $k!$ is polynomial-time problem.

My whole question is general as the title mentions:  Can we use exponential function in a reduction to create some parameter in the instance of the concerned problem?

**EDIT**

My question is motivated by [the validity of using exponentiation in polytime reduction](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37102/validity-of-exponentiation-in-a-polynomial-time-reduction) on cstheory.SE where the OP asks about a specific reduction used in some paper. My question is general about using exponentiation in reduction.

Comment: do you mean that $f(k)$  takes exponential time, or literally just calculates an exponant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of notation, I'm going to assume you're trying to produce a polynomial time reduction $f$, which that maps instances $x$ of some problem $L_1$ to instances $f(x)$ of some other problem $L_2$.  Instances of $L_i$ have parameter $p_i$ ($i\in\{1,2\}$).  Since the reduction has to run in polynomial time, it has to output at most a polynomial number of bits, say $|x|^q$ for some constant $q$. In particular, the representation of $p_2$ can't be more than $|x|^q$ bits long.

So, suppose the value of the parameter is $k$ in some instance $x$ with parameter $p_1=k$. Whether or not $f(x)$ can have parameter $p_2=2^k$ depends entirely on what the parameters are and how big $p_1$ can be.

If $p_1$ is a number represented in unary, we have $p_1\leq |x|$; if it's a number represented in binary or some higher base, then $p_1 = O(2^{|x|})$. If $p_1$ is the size of some object described in $x$, then its size will depend on what kind of object it is (e.g., if $p_1$ is the size of some set of a graph's the vertices, $p_1\leq |x|$; if it's the number of pairs of vertices with some property, $p_1\leq |x|^2$, and so on).

And, now, what's $p_2$? If it's a number in unary, then $2^k$ is a string of length $2^k$, so we need $2^k\leq |x|^q$, i.e., $k=O(\log |x|)$. If it's a number in binary, then $2^k$ is just a $1$ followed by $k$ zeroes, so we can write this in our output as long as $k=O(|x|^q)$. If it's the size of some structure then, again, it depends on how that structure is represented. For example, if you need to add $2^k$ vertices, you need all those vertices to be stored in at most $|x|^q$ characters, so $k$ had better not be any bigger than about $\log n$.